# ErrorException Undefined variable | Laravel , php

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view, controller

i'm new to Laravel.

I have trouble in showing data to a view page with this error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $ikus (View: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\SKP-PA-BKT\resources\views\iku.blade.php)
```

And Laravel give me solution:

```
$ikus is undefined
```

Here is code in iku.blade.php :

```
@extends('layouts.sidebar')

@section('content')

<section class="main-panel">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-wrap">
                    <table class="table table-responsive-xl">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No </th>
                                <th>Opsi</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="alert">
                                @foreach ($ikus as $iku)
                                <td>{{ $iku->id }}</td>
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

Here's code in IkuController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers

use App\Models\Iku;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IkuController extends Controller
{
    public function getIku()
    {
        $ikus = Iku::all();
        //dd($ikus);
        return view('iku', compact('ikus'));
    }
}
```

And here's in web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\IkuController;

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/indikator-kinerja', [IkuController::class, 'getIku'])->name('iku');
```

It seems the $ikus variable from IkuController.php file can not be accessed by iku.blade.php file.
I have looked for solutions and most of what i've found is to add code like this:

```
    return view ('layouts.index')->with(['features' => $features]);
```

or like this one:

```
return view ('layouts.index', compact('features'));
```

in IkuController.php file.

I have added it as written above. But i still get the same error. Is there anything left?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your view is cached, you most likely ran the command

```
php artisan optimize
```

So just clear your view cache by doing:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

For the future, you can always see what is being cached by doing

```
php artisan about
```

[image]